# Integrity Checking for NPM Packages

Tags: npm, windows-10, checksum

I'm being tasked to validate the integrity of my downloads from npm by our IT/Security department. I'm a programmer and while I understand at a top level what performing a sha checksum is, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that on my NPM packages.

I successfully performed a check on a single file download from the browser for something other than npm. NPM installs come with an "integrity" value in the "package-lock.json", but I am unsure how to use that value. For example when trying to perform this check on the D3 library which has the "integrity" value of "sha512-4PL5hHaHwX4m7Zr1UapXW23apo6pexCgdetdJ5kTmADpG/7T9Gkxw0M0tf/pjoB63ezCCm0u5UaFYy2aMt0Mcw==" I have been unable to recreate that value. I tried to create a tarball of the package folder using 7zip, and I even tried directly downloading the ".tgz" file from the "resolved" value "https://registry.npmjs.org/d3/-/d3-5.16.0.tgz" which still does not yield the right checksum.

I have used both of the following commands which both give me the same result. (e0f2f9847687c17e26ed9af551aa575b6ddaa68ea97b10a075eb5d2799139800e91bfed3f46931c34334b5ffe98e807addecc20a6d2ee54685632d9a32dd0c73)

```
Get-FileHash -Path C:\Path\to\d3-5.16.0.tgz -Algorithm SHA512
certutil -hashfile C:\Path\to\d3-5.16.0.tgz sha512
```

If anyone can walk me through what I'm doing wrong or missing it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You just missed out one step, you need to **convert the result (HEX) to base64 instead.**
The result you generated is in Hexadecimal (by default), unless you explicitly mention to use base64 encoding while creating the hash.

**Summary**:

1. Have your file hashed with algorithm of your choice (eg: SHA-256)
2. By default, it will create a hash of Hexadecimal. You need to convert it into Base64-encoded hash.

**Option 1**: You can generate SRI hashes from the command-line with openssl using a command invocation 
 `cat FILENAME.js | openssl dgst -sha384 -binary | openssl base64 -A`

**Option 2**: Or with shasum 
`shasum -b -a 384 FILENAME.js | awk '{ print $1 }' | xxd -r -p | base64`

**Option 3**: Use online tools.

1. Firstly, upload and hash your file with any online tool (I was using
   [this](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/index.html)) and it should create a Hexadecimal hash output.
2. Then, convert your Hexadecimal hash output into Base64-encoded value. (I
   was using [this](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/hex))

**References**:

- [W3's Subresource Integrity](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/)